# What is a "utenza fissa"?

Tags: word-meaning, translation

While filling out an address form, I came across the field "Utenza fissa". I checked dictionaries and online translators. The result was not very satisfying:

I found the following meanings for "Utenza fissa":

- Fixed user
- Fixed utility

and combinations of the words "fixed" and "utility" with other words, none of which made sense.
My personal guess would be "Username". *What is the translation of "Utenza fissa"?*

Comment: I think you might need to give a little more context. I suspect they are asking for a landline (*fisso* in Italian) phone number, but it could be many other things. What are the neighbouring fields?

Comment: Name and Address(Country, City, Street, CAP) @DenisNardin

Comment: I agree with @DenisNardin: it looks like an involved, bureaucratese way to say “(Landline) phone number”.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can depend on the context, but the term *utenza fissa* is often used to denote a landline telephone number, for example see [here](http://tariffe.segugio.it/guide-e-strumenti/domande-frequenti/come-si-attiva-un-utenza-telefonica-fissa.aspx) or [here](http://www.ilgiornale.it/news/tecnologia/profezia-sul-telefono-lutenza-fissa-scomparir-2018-1231353.html).

**Utenza** is a generic term that means an account with some utility provider. A priori it could refer to electricity, gas or many other things. What makes me think it is referring to the phone number is the term **fissa**. In Italian a *telefono fisso* (lit. fixed phone) is a landline phone as opposed to a *mobile phone* (which is after all the only kind of phone you can move around). While there are other kinds of unmovable utilities, the only one which has commonly both a fixed and a mobile version is the phone.

Note that the term **utenza fissa** in this sense is rather bureaucratic and would never be used in common conversation. Normally people would say *numero fisso* instead or even just *un fisso* (lit. a fixed one).

Answer (score 3):

Utenza fissa almost always stands for 'landline telephone' opposed to 'utenza mobile' or 'cellulare' which is a mobile line. (I'm italian and I've always heard it in these terms).

For practical use, in Italy, if you see a number beginning with '0' is a landline, if it begins with '3' it's a mobile line.